# How to define dynamic values as constant in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a following method where i am simply submit the form and works absolutely fine
but i need to defie the follwing path in constant

```
$pathToStoreFile = public_path() . '/cases/' . $caseNumber . '/filesBefore/' . $revisions;
```

How can i do that. if i define in config then how can i pass the dynamic values in config array.

or if do  `define("pathToStoreFile", public_path() . '/cases/' . $caseNumber . '/filesBefore/' . $revisions);` then is there any difference in

`$pathToStoreFile = public_path() . '/cases/' . $caseNumber . '/filesBefore/' . $revisions;` and  `define("pathToStoreFile", public_path() . '/cases/' . $caseNumber . '/filesBefore/' . $revisions);`

```
public function caseSubmit(CaseStoreRequest $request)
        {
            $validator = $request->validated();

            $allowedfileExtension = ['stl'];

            $portal = $request->input('portal');
            $case_number = $request->input('case_number');
            $file_before = $request->file_before;
            $file_after = $request->file_after;

            $user_id = Auth::id();

            $caseifExist = Cases::where('case_number', "$case_number")->first();

            if ($caseifExist != null) {
                $caseId = $caseifExist->id;
                $caseNumber = $caseifExist->case_number;

                $number_of_patients = Cases::find($caseId)->patients;
                $revisions = count($number_of_patients) + 1;

            } elseif ($caseifExist == null) {

                $revisions = 0;
                $caseInputData = ['patient_name' => $patient_name,
                    'doctor_name' => $doctor_name,
                    'case_number' => $case_number,
                    'created_at' => $date,
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'portal_id' => $portal_id
                ];

                $case = new Cases();

                $case_data = $case->storePatientCase($caseInputData);
                $caseId = $case_data->id;
                $caseNumber = $case_data->case_number;
            }

                /** code for move files before **/
               $pathToStoreFile = public_path() . '/cases/' . $caseNumber . '/filesBefore/' . $revisions;
                $filesBefore = $this->multiplefileUpload(pathToStoreFile, $file_before, $allowedfileExtension);
                $pathToStoreFile = public_path() . '/cases/' . $caseNumber . '/filesAfter/' . $revisions;
                $filesAfter = $this->multiplefileUpload($pathToStoreFile, $file_after, $allowedfileExtension);

        }
```

Comment: You cannot define dynamic value as constant. Constant is not dynamic.

Comment: any better way to write 

`$pathToStoreFile = public_path() . '/cases/' . $caseNumber . '/filesBefore/' . $revisions;
                $filesBefore = $this->multiplefileUpload(pathToStoreFile, $file_before, $allowedfileExtension);
                $pathToStoreFile = public_path() . '/cases/' . $caseNumber . '/filesAfter/' . $revisions;
                $filesAfter = $this->multiplefileUpload($pathToStoreFile, $file_after, $allowedfileExtension);`